# Connect Ruby/Rails to ipad via local network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ipad

host ip: 192.168.1.2

ipad ip: 192.168.1.3

when working on my host, the web address is: localhost.dev:3000/sign_in/
When I try to connect to my ipad via 192.168.1.2.dev:3000/sign_in the connection times out.

One method to overcome my issue was to change the wifi settings on the ipad to manual proxy:

server: 192.168.1.2

port: 3000

Now 192.168.1.2.dev works! Kinda...

I can now log in to my site, but js seems to be broken and the ipad changes the url to: ( http://2.dev/page ) Normally it would be ( http://localhost.dev:3000/page ) Which I believe is the last digit of the host lan ip. We use some externally hosted js files. Which may be why it is breaking. I can NOT browse the internet (on ipad) while the proxy is enabled. What am I missing?

(192.168.1.2:3000 does not work for any device..)

After further debugging I believe it is because of internet connectivity through the proxy.

The exact error my log spits out is:

```
 CONNECT configuration.apple.com:443 HTTP/1.1
 Host: configuration.apple.com
 User-Agent: ubd/289.3 CFNetwork/672.1.14 Darwin/14.0.0
 Connection: keep-alive
 Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

 2015-04-20 11:52:54] ERROR TypeError: can't dup NilClass
 /home/pete/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httprequest.rb:279:in `dup'
```

So I think I have to enable linux to forward my internet as well?

Comment: "Now 192.168.1.6.dev works!" - 6?

Comment: Sorry.. I will change the typo.

Comment: Try to put `192.168.1.2 rubyhost.dev` into `/etc/hosts` file _on iPad_ and navigate to `rubyhost.dev:3000`.

Comment: This is a work ipad. I can not jail break it. Plus, it feels really weird to jailbreak something to develop for it. Apple... sigh..

Comment: `HOSTALIASES` might help you http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104511/55106

Answer (score 12):

Rails is not accessible, because the server binds to *localhost*.

Here's my usual workflow using [zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) / Bonjour and Mac OS X, although it should basically work with another OS and / or a fixed IP address, too.

1. Open System Preferences > Sharing to look up your computer's [.local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) name:

   [image: System Preferences > Sharing]
2. Add the host name to `config/environments/development.rb` so you access the server by that name, e.g.: (required for Rails 6+ see: Blocked host Error)

   ```
   Rails.application.configure do
     # ...
     config.hosts << 'stefans-mac.local'
     # ...
   end
   ```
3. Start `rails server` with the `-b` option to provide the host name (this is the important part):

   ```
    $ rails s -b stefans-mac.local
    => Booting Thin
    => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://stefans-mac.local:3000
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    >> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
    >> Maximum connections set to 1024
    >> Listening on stefans-mac.local:3000, CTRL+C to stop
   ```
4. Assuming you've enabled [iCloud Tabs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202530), visit the URL on your Mac using Safari (so you don't have to enter the address manually on your iPad)
5. On your iPad / iPhone, open Safari, tap the Tabs icon, scroll down and select the Rails tab:

[image: iPhone]

6. Done:

[image: Safari]

Comment: Rails 6+ you'll find that instead of everything working you instead have a "blocked host" message. [There is a SO question for this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878453/upgraded-rails-to-6-getting-blocked-host-error)

Comment: @notapatch have you tried to add the server’s host name to `config.hosts`?

Comment: yes, everything works perfectly once you alter the config.hosts, thanks. My comment was a help to people who after following your excellent answer are left with a "blocked host" and wondering what to do next and if they did anything wrong (obviously, they didn't). A better long term solution would be to edit your answer, but I didn't feel confident enough when I wrote the comment (I was worried I was mistaken).

Comment: @notapatch I've updated the answer. Somehow I would've expected Rails to add the host from `-b` automatically to the `config.hosts` array.

Comment: Looks good. Yes, I was also confused why there wasn't a generic configuration in the development config. I went with `config.hosts.clear` solution because otherwise everyone on the team would have their own version of the development config. However, I didn't understand the security implications enough to put it in a SO answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what Ruby on Rails version you're on but somewhere around version 4, Rails changed the default binding address from `0.0.0.0` to only `localhost`. By default this allows you to only access the Rails app via `localhost:3000` or `127.0.0.1:3000` - which is fine in most cases.

Now if you'd like to access the app from an iPad on your local network (or any device on your local network) you can use the `-b` option when starting the server and specify a binding address of `0.0.0.0`

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

This will bind on ALL interfaces including localhost and the IP assigned by your network. You should now be able to access the app via your iPad. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

If I were you, I would try [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). that way you can temporarily and securely expose your dev machine's localhost:3000 to the ipad. Download ngrok to your application's folder and `unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip`.

For me that looks like: 
`unzip ngrok_2.0.16_darwin_amd64.zip`

Then run `rails s`.

Finally  `./ngrok http 3000`.

This command will give you an address to hit from your ipad. When you're done just kill ngrok with `ctrl+c`.

I get the following output:

```
NAME:
ngrok - tunnel local ports to public URLs and inspect traffic

ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                              (Ctrl+C to quit)

Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0.16/2.0.15
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://014da213.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000
Forwarding                    https://014da213.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000

Connnections                  ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Type the forwarding address into your ipad. For me, `http://014da213.ngrok.io`

No config required!

Comment: I tried following your instructions, but it tells me to setup ngrok... So i followed the help instructions and in my server log for ngrok: ( GET /                          302 Found   ) But then it redirects the ipad to ngrok.com

Comment: Im not sure what you changed, but following the instructions always redirects to ngrok.com

Comment: I changed ./ngrok to ./ngrok http 3000, which tells ngrok what to listen to. Are you using http or https? What is your tunnel status? Does your output look like mine?

Comment: Can you visit the web portal while running ngrok? Go to localhost:4040 and see what's going on. Check the docs here https://ngrok.com/docs/2#expose

Comment: I talked with the creator for a while.. I (kinda) got it up and running.. But im still getting errors.. Cool program tho! And great response time when asking questions through the page

Comment: Yeah, they're great! What did you have to do to get it working? I'd love to update my answer for future googlers.

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.1.6` is an ip address, eg the address of your computer on the local network.

`:3000` is a port number (well, 3000 is the number, the ":" just separates it from the ip address), in this case the port which Rails runs on.

`localhost.dev` is an alias set up on your machine, probably for `127.0.0.1` which is the standard "this computer, ie the 'local host'" ip address.

I wouldn't have expected `192.168.1.2.dev` to work at all because it's not a valid ip address - it's an ip address with the last bit of your alias on the end.

You should use "192.168.1.2:3000" on your ipad to connect to your local computer's rails server.  You shouldn't need to change your proxy settings (so set them back to normal).

If you specifically want to use a particular domain name on your ipad (when you access your rails app), which can be useful if your app displays the site differently based on the domain or subdomain that it was accessed via, then you can use the awesome http://xip.io/ .  This is probably more complicated than you need though, it sounds like you just want to see what your rails app looks like on an ipad.

Comment: 192.168.1.2:3000 does not work on any machine. Ipad or localhost. localhost:3000 does not work on localhost either.

Comment: It's odd that your local computer can't even connect to itself over the network.  Are you sure that you have the right IP address for it?  How are you getting the address?

Comment: the address is 192.168.1.2.dev