# Upgraded Rails to 6, getting Blocked host Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9, ruby-on-rails-6

I needed the new function in ActiveStorage to resize_to_fill so I upgraded to Ruby 2.5.1 and Rails 6.

```
ruby '2.5.1'

gem "rails", github: "rails/rails"
```

When I stopped, then restarted my server (Cloud 9), I received the below Rails error:

```
Blocked host: xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.c9users.io
To allow requests to xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.c9users.io, add the following configuration:

Rails.application.config.hosts << "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.c9users.io"
```

I've tried restarting, new windows, but nothing worked. I've never seen this error before. I'm guessing the new version of Rails is doing something?

Comment: I created a new app to test if it was my original app or every app. It was already running ruby 2.5.1. I changed the Gemfile to use edge Rails (6), `gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'` as I did before. I started the server and it did the same thing, gave the same error.

Comment: I added `Rails.application.config.hosts << "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.c9users.io"` to `config/application.rb` and it fixed my test app fine. Then I did it to my real app and it also worked. The problem is, Devise threw an error as well, which apparently won't be fixed until at least Rails 6 beta. I guess I'm going back to Carrierwave for my image sizing needs until ActiveStorage is more mature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added `Rails.application.config.hosts << "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.c9users.io"` to `config/application.rb` and it fixed my test app fine. Then I did it to my real app and it also worked. The problem is, Devise threw an error as well, which apparently won't be fixed until at least Rails 6 beta. I guess I'm going back to `Carrierwave` for my image sizing needs until `ActiveStorage` is more mature.

Answer (score 135):

The Blocked Host is a new feature of Rails 6. You can add this pattern to your `config/environments/development.rb` to have no worries of that in case of dynamic urls

```
config.hosts << /[a-z0-9]+\.c9users\.io/
```

Also for ngrok user, just replace above `c9users` by `ngrok`

**Update:** ngrok is currently using `-` and `.` as subdomain in their URLs so this should be accurate `config.hosts << /[a-z0-9-.]+\.ngrok\.io/`

Source: https://github.com/MikeRogers0/puma-ngrok-tunnel

Comment: Best answer imo, since it shows usage of regex. Noteworthy: I had to **restart my rails server** in order for the change to take effect. Ymmv.

Comment: Honestly, this is the best solution for NGROK users, because it allows you to get rid of those stupid gems that make you do this anyway. +10000

Comment: Great answer, however be aware that ngrok can use dashes (-) in their URLs so the best regex for ngrok will be `config. hosts << /[a-z0-9-]+\.ngrok\.io/`

Comment: Just do `config.hosts << '.c9users.io'`, this takes care of any subdomain and is simpler. See my answer for details.

Comment: Note that ngrok can use multiple level subdomain like 123.eu.ngrok.io so adding a dot would cover that case as well: `config.hosts << /[a-z0-9-.]+\.ngrok\.io/`

Comment: The last dash in `[a-z0-9-.]` looks like a special character, might be better to escape it: `[a-z0-9\-.]`

Comment: `config.hosts << /[a-z0-9\-]+\.ngrok-free\.app/` is required for free accounts

Answer (score 86):

If you want to disable this functionality on your development environment, you can add `config.hosts.clear` to `config/environments/development.rb`.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but `config.hosts.clear` did.

Comment: You're correct; I edited the answer to change it.

Comment: This is the best option IMHO for development env. For production environments it's better to set the restriction correctly.

Comment: Don't do this. Disabling this functionality leaves your localhost vulnerable to DNS rebinding attacks, resulting in attackers potentially getting full access to your local Rails app. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 44):

Add [these](https://rubular.com/r/wNBqWa2YKKd75I) lines to `config/environments/development.rb`

```rb
  config.hosts << /.*\.ngrok\.io/
  config.hosts << /.*\.ngrok-free\.app/
```

**Restart** your rails server and it will work

Note: As of 2023, ngrok now requires an auth token. If you haven't set it up, go [here](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup), log in, and copy the line it gives you to your terminal:

```
ngrok config add-authtoken <your token>
```

You should be up and going in a couple of minutes. If you get stuck, there's a nice explainer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWixLZgzOHM)

Comment: You regex doesn't always work depending on the server you get. I get a xxxx.eu.ngrok.io domain name.  (.eu is added before the ngrok.io domainname)

Comment: @gamecreature thanks for letting me know. I updated the answer to generalise the regex. I think it's simpler now, and less fragile.

Answer (score 16):

This [article](https://www.fngtps.com/2019/rails6-blocked-host/) worked for me:

1. The first option is to whitelist the hostnames in `config/environments/development.rb`:

   ```
   Rails.application.configure do
     config.hosts << "hostname" # Whitelist one hostname
     config.hosts << /application\.local\Z/ # Whitelist a test domain
   end
   ```
2. The second option is to clear the entire whitelist, which lets through requests for all hostnames:

   ```
   Rails.application.configure do
     config.hosts.clear
   end
   ```

Credit goes to **Manfred Stienstra**.

Answer (score 16):

To allow requests from any subdomain of `ngrok.io` (or other service), the simplest solution is to prepend it with `.` like so:

```
# config/environments/development.rb

Rails.application.configure do

  ...

  config.hosts << '.ngrok.io'
end
```

No need to use a regexp for subdomains like mentioned in some other answers.

PS: don't disable this functionality by doing `config.hosts.clear` as mentioned in some other answers, as this defeats the purpose of Rails' DNS rebinding protection, and under the right circumstances an outside attacker could gain full access to your local Rails app information ([source](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/31/rails-6-adds-guard-against-dns-rebinding-attacks.html)).

Comment: I sure hope people aren't running Production code under an `development` environment.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 6 Action Pack introduced ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization and by default allows only [IPAddr.new(“0.0.0.0/0”), IPAddr.new(“::/0”), “localhost”]

You can add arrays of RegExp, Proc, IPAddr and String or a single String in the file  config/application.rb like this

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.hosts << "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.c9users.io"
  ...
end
```

From "https://drivy.engineering/rails-6-unnoticed-features":

> Rails 6 added a new middleware called
>   ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization allowing you to whitelist some hosts
>   for your application and preventing [Host header attacks](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-a-host-header-attack). You can
>   easily configure it with a String, IPAddr, Proc and RegExp (useful
>   when dealing with wildcard domains).

Comment: A little late in seeing this one but thanks for the info. I'll have to check this out.

Comment: Rails.application.config.hosts << ".product.com"   allows all sub domains for product.com - at least in Rails 6

Answer (score 5):

`config.hosts = nil`

Use this in `development.rb` and and restart your rails server, it works for me, it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

In `Rails 6`, when you want to allow host from `ngrok v2.3.40`, add this config into `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.hosts << /[a-z0-9\-]+\.ap\.ngrok\.io/
```

Restart server and enjoy

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to config/environments/development.rb

`config.hosts << /.+\.ngrok\.io:\d+/`

Most of the responses I see are missing the *port* part of the URL. If you are accessing this URL in a specific port (typically `:3000`) the `:\d+` part of the regular expression is necessary.

It will work after restarting your server.

Comment: I have been using Rails 6 since it was released and never had to add localhost to config allowed hosts, until 2022. I guess maybe a small point release added the requirement to add the port, so I appreciate this response mentioning it. Thanks!

Comment: yes, that's weird. I don't have to add it for localhost, because it's added by default. You shouldn't need to add it unless you are removing the defaults somewhere.

Comment: Can't emphasize this enough! I get many many questions from people who have just followed the literal instructions in the "helpful" Rails error page to add a hostname to config.hosts, but it's also important to include the port number or at least a regex that matches a port number!

Answer (score 2):

In order to support hyphens in the ngrok subdomain name and region, you need to change `config/environments/development.rb` change `config.hosts` to `/[a-z0-9.-]+.ngrok.io/`

Example:

```
  config.hosts = (config.hosts rescue []) << /[a-z0-9.-]+.ngrok.io/
```

Answer (score 1):

HEADS UP : You may whitelist your host with the config `application.config.hosts << 'your_unvalid_host_name'` but still have the error.
The error message is currently not accurate in this case. See this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41545).
You should not use hostname with underscore.
NB: The `application.config.hosts.clear` is working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The rails 7 and 8 way to do this is via:

```
config.host_authorization = { exclude: ->(request) { request.path =~ /healthcheck/ } }
```

or if you want to use the host instead of the path

```
config.host_authorization = { exclude: ->(request) { request.host =~ /ngrok/ } }
```

See [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#actiondispatch-hostauthorization).

Answer (score -1):

1st run the ngrok 3000 in one of the terminals and next open the new terminal and run rails s... then u can see now ngrok and rails s both can run simultaneously...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).