# Why ngrok send me a 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webhooks, ngrok

I try to work with a webhook to get a JSON, 
I read that I should install ngrok because webhooks do not work locally, so I installed ngrok, 
and tried to follow this small tuto : https://medium.com/@derek_dyer/rails-webhooks-local-development-7b7c755d85e3

I created my routes :

```
get 'invoice/webhooks'
post 'invoice/webhooks' =>'invoice#webhooks'
```

And my controller :

```
def webhooks
   render json: response.body, status: 200
end
```

I also plugged my URL : https://ce0d99f7.ngrok.io/invoice/webhooks in my service to receive the webhook

I run ./ngrok http 3000 in my terminal and I receive a message

```
POST /invoice/webhooks         403 Forbidden
```

Is anyone knows how to fix that ?

Comment: The "message" you mentioned is from the ngrok's output, right? I'd say it works as expected -  just forwards the request to the app server. I'd check the app server error log/console output to get more context about the error...

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Yes the message is from the console where I started ngrok !

Comment: Is there any kind of authentication on controller on before_action callback?

Comment: Nope nothing, I did some modification and now I have a 422 Unprocessable Entity for the POST /invoice/webhooks

Comment: Added skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token in my controller fixed the problem, I now have a 200 OK on my POST /invoice/webhooks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you using rails 6 and use ngrok in development you must edit the development.rb file in config/environments for add `config.hosts << "a0000000.ngrok.io"` where a0000000.ngrok.io  is the url supplied by ngrok without `https://` , if this no work so you must add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in you controller.

Comment: I have my ngrok tunnel address in my .env file for local testing, so in my development.rb file I just have `config.hosts << ENV['NGROK_TUNNEL_ADDRESS']`. This way I don't need to touch the development.rb when I start a new ngrok session, just the .env file.

Comment: WITHOUT HTTPS was what did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

@daniel0318's answer is exactly right. I just wanted to mention you can use [this regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166980/5783745) to allow all traffic through ngrok (add to `development.rb`):

```rb
# /config/environments/development.rb

config.hosts << /.*\.ngrok\.io/
```

**Restart** your server, and it will work.

One last note: over the years ngrok has changed their URLs several times; ensure you have the up to date regex above (others may not work).