# Can't get 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header from fetch request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension, cors, fetch-api

I'm building a Chrome extension in React that's connected to a Rails 6 app for the backend. I want the Rails app to act as an API and store data from the extension, but I can't get it to accept requests from my extension.

Here's my fetch code in my extension:

```
    fetch('https://www.myapp.com/api/post_comment/test', {
     method: 'get',
     headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    });
```

and here's the errors I keep getting in my js console:

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.myapp.com/api/test' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

> The FetchEvent for "https://www.myapp.com/api/test" resulted in a network
> error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to
> respondWith().

I tried adding the rack-cors gem to my Rails app:

```
#Gemfile:

gem 'rack-cors'

#config/initializers/cors.rb:

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '/api/*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put]
  end
end
```

and I also tried adding the header manually in my Rails app controller:

```
before_action :cors_preflight_check
after_action :cors_set_access_control_headers


def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
end

# If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the
# request, return only the necessary headers and return an empty
# text/plain.

def cors_preflight_check
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
end
```

But I'm still getting the error. Anyone know how I can fix this?

If I add `mode: 'no-cors',` to my fetch code, I'm able to post data, but I can't retrieve data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

move your config from `config/cors.rb` to `config/initializers/cors.rb`

all files in `config/initializers/` will be loaded on rails startup.

also it could be possible to blocked by rails 6 new feature to block unwanted hosts.

add following snippet to `config/application.rb` or env specific file in `config/environments/`

```
  config.hosts.clear
```

check [Upgraded Rails to 6, getting Blocked host Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878453/upgraded-rails-to-6-getting-blocked-host-error)

Comment: Good catch, but I moved the file and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: remove this cors_set_access_control_headers, and cors_preflight_check. not needed

Comment: This actually was the problem - I noticed that I was actually being redirected to an error page, which wasn't covered under the cors.rb file, and that's why I was still getting the message. One I stopped redirecting to the error page, it finally started working.

Answer (score 1):

In an extension you have two origins - origin of the page the content script is injected to and background script origin.

For background script to be able to connect to your api - you need to add `"https://www.myapp.com/"` to manifest's `permissions`, it is not subject to regular CORS checking. Content script can talk to background via [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), and thus may avoid CORS:

```js
// from content script:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "doSomeAction"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```js
//in background script:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url : "from the extension");
    if (request.action == "doSomeAction") {
      fetch('https://www.myapp.com/api/post_comment/test', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
      }).then(function(response){
        // do something with response and pass pack to content script:
        sendResponse({foo: "bar"});
      });
      return true; // keep message channel so sendResponse is available in 
    }
  });
```

As for rails CORS - I'd start with ensuring the header is present:

```sh
curl -IX OPTIONS https://www.myapp.com/api/post_comment/test -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -H 'Origin: http://someorigin.example.com'
```

this should return something like:

```
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx
date: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 19:50:00 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: http://someorigin.example.com
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
access-control-expose-headers:
access-control-max-age: 7200
cache-control: no-cache
x-request-id: 5846b7400a15b19398c96bec7faac570
x-runtime: 0.001532
```